# pure js load html and js using ajax, but js not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, knockout.js

i want load html file using ajax and execute script.
this is my html file to load :

```
<div class="panel panel-body">
    <h4>Personal Data</h4>
    <hr />
    <span data-bind="editable: firstName"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>
</div>

<script>
    (function () {
        console.log('lala');

        var viewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.id = ko.observable();
            self.firstName = ko.observable('YZ');
            self.lastName = ko.observable();
            self.gender = ko.observable();

            self.genders = ko.observableArray();
        }
        var vm = new viewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    })
</script>
```

and this is how i load and execute :

```
Mark.load(t.pathToTemplate, t, function (htmlTemplate, path, option) {
                    var wrap = document.createElement('div');
                    wrap.innerHTML = htmlTemplate;
                    var scripts = wrap.getElementsByTagName('script');
                    if (scripts.length > 0) {
                        var newjs = document.createElement('script');
                        newjs.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (newjs.readyState === 'loaded' || newjs.readyState === 'complete') {
                                cb();
                            }
                        };
                        newjs.onload = function () {
                            cb();
                        };
                        newjs.innerHTML = scripts[0].innerHTML;
                        document.body.appendChild(newjs);
                    }
                    document.getElementById(option.renderIn).innerHTML = htmlTemplate;

                });
Mark.load = function (path, option, callback) {
            var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
            xobj.open('GET', path, true);
            xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                    callback(xobj.responseText, path, option);
                }
            };
            xobj.send(null);
        }
```

load and append work correctly but js not executed.
how to append or add that js script to document and execute it using pure js?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring anonymous function but you are not executing it. You need to add `()` at the end of the function to execute it:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        console.log('lala');

        var viewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.id = ko.observable();
            self.firstName = ko.observable();
            self.lastName = ko.observable();
            self.gender = ko.observable();

            self.genders = ko.observableArray();
        }
        var vm = new viewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks it works for console.log(), but knockoutjs apply bindings not working, i mean it looks like ko.applyBindings(vm); not execute or not applied. fyi i update my code